# How do you use event.not-before argument in aws ec2 describe-instance-status?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I want to get only the statuses with events in the future. I can search for `[Complete]` string in `description` field, but I want to use `event.not-before` filter and filter it out from the AWS side.

However, whenever I set `event.not-before` filter, I get no statuses back.

I tried this command, expecting the full result.

```
$ aws ec2 describe-instance-status --filters "Name=event.not-before,Values=2014-09-15T17:15:20.000Z"
```

However, I am getting nothing back.

Can someone spot what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CLI doesn't work in the way you expect. It will filter the results that match your criteria. For example:

```
aws ec2 describe-instance-status --filters Name=event.not-before,Values=2016-11-21T12:00:00.000Z
```

it will look for instances which have events with `not-before` equals the value specified. The above query results in an instance with:

```
    "Events": [
        {
            "Code": "instance-stop",
            "Description": "You're instance will be stopped",
            "NotBefore": "2016-11-21T12:00:00.000Z"
        },
        {
```

So, the `not-before` value has to match exactly.